# Filtering one dataset using the Observations in another dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two datasets. The first dataset looks like -

```
data.frame (year = rep(2005:2022,2), CompanyID = rep(6:7, each = 18))
year        CompanyID
1  2005         6
2  2006         6
3  2007         6
4  2008         6
5  2009         6
6  2010         6
7  2011         6
8  2012         6
9  2013         6
10 2014         6
11 2015         6
12 2016         6
13 2017         6
14 2018         6
15 2019         6
16 2020         6
17 2021         6
18 2022         6
19 2005         7
20 2006         7
21 2007         7
22 2008         7
23 2009         7
24 2010         7
25 2011         7
26 2012         7
27 2013         7
28 2014         7
29 2015         7
30 2016         7
31 2017         7
32 2018         7
33 2019         7
34 2020         7
35 2021         7
36 2022         7
```

The second data set looks like this -

```
data.frame (year = c(2012, 2007, 2015, 2009), CompanyID = c(6,6,7,7))
   year     CompanyID
1 2012         6
2 2007         6
3 2015         7
4 2009         7
```

Now I want the following -

In the first dataset, I want to keep the observations one year before (`t-1`) and one year after (`t+1`) of the `year` variable from second dataset as the `CompanyID` in first dataset and second dataset are the same. So my expected output should look like this -

```
   year CompanyID POST
1 2006         6    0
2 2008         6    1
3 2011         6    0
4 2013         6    1
5 2008         7    0
6 2010         7    1
7 2014         7    0
8 2016         7    1
```

The `POST` variable is also needed to identify the observations before year (`t-1`) or after year (`t+1`)

I have many observations for many `CompanyID`, but here I show data only for two `CompanyID`, which are 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First modify your second dataset (`df_ref` in my code) to include one year before and after the target, also a `POST` column specifying if it's before or after. Then join the two together.

```r
library(dplyr)

df_data <- data.frame (year = rep(2005:2022,2), CompanyID = rep(6:7, each = 18))
df_ref <- data.frame (year = c(2012, 2007, 2015, 2009), CompanyID = c(6,6,7,7))

df_ref |> 
  reframe(year = c(year - 1, year + 1), POST = c(0, 1), .by = c(year, CompanyID)) |> 
  left_join(df_data, by = c("year", "CompanyID"))

  year CompanyID POST
1 2011         6    0
2 2013         6    1
3 2006         6    0
4 2008         6    1
5 2014         7    0
6 2016         7    1
7 2008         7    0
8 2010         7    1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do:

```
df[df$year %in% years, ] |> 
  (\(x) { x$POST <- ifelse(x$year %in% (df2$year + 1), 1, 0)
  return(x)
  })()

 
 
year CompanyID POST
2   2006    6   0   
4   2008    6   1   
7   2011    6   0   
9   2013    6   1
```

Larger df = df and smaller = df2.

We create a condition based on required years

```
years <- c((df2$year + 1), (df2$year - 1)) 

2013 2008 2011 2006
```

Subset our df

```
df3 <- df[df$year %in% years, ]

    
    year CompanyID
2   2006    6       
4   2008    6       
7   2011    6       
9   2013    6
```

Then add another columns to our df

```
x$POST <- ifelse(df3$year %in% (df2$year + 1), 1, 0)
```

***Update***

For multiple columns, you can split on the columns, in this case, I split on `companyID` but it can be more than 1

```
lapply(split(df2, df2$CompanyID), \(new_df2) {
  years <- c((new_df2$year + 1), (new_df2$year - 1))
  df[(df$year %in% years) & (df$CompanyID %in% new_df2$CompanyID), ] |> 
    (\(x) { x$POST <- ifelse(x$year %in% (new_df2$year + 1), 1, 0)
  return(x)
  })()
}) |> 
  do.call(what = rbind, args = _)
```

Comment: It worked fine for one CmpanyID, e.g., 6, but if there is more than one CompanyID in larger df, it does not work well. I little modified your code to take care of more than one CompanyID, but it does not work well. Here is the modified code - `df1 %>% 
  group_by(CompanyID, year) %>% 
  .[.$year %in% years, ] %>%  
  (\(x) { x$POST <- ifelse(x$year %in% (df2$year + 1), 1, 0)
  return(x)
  })()`